# Can a messagelistener or mdb be stateful?

Tags: ejb, message-driven-bean, jca, stateful

related to my question on jca inbound transaction management.
[How to control XAResource in inbound jca resource adapter for conversational transaction?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28881889/how-to-control-xaresource-in-inbound-jca-resource-adapter-for-conversational-tra/28882053#28882053)

For an inbound resource adapter I need to keep a transaction open and execute different actions in that transaction.

This could be solved by making the message endpoint @Stateful, but It's unclear to me wether that is allowed.

The 3.1 EJB spec states (section 5.1)

***Message-driven bean instances have no conversational state. This means that all bean instances are equivalent when they are not involved in servicing a client message.***

I found a post from David Blevins, founder of TomiTribe (the company behin TomEE), stating that it would be allowed.
https://github.com/dblevins/jca-quickstart/wiki/Inbound-Connectors-MDBs-Today

Another approach would be trying to  manage the XAResrouce myself, but no luck there yet...

edited:
Note that the JCA spec states (section 13.5)

***Note that the endpoint instance supplied by the createEndPoint method call is a
proxy which implements the endpoint message listener type and the
MessageEndpoint interface and it is not the actual endpoint.***

So, afaik there is no guarantee that the actual listener is the same everytime you go through the proxy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let me answer my own question.

There is nothing in the specification that would allow this. The sections referred to in the specification state that mdbs are not stateful.

However, I was in contact with David Blevins, who answered:
 "Short answer is they are stateful for Wildfly and TomEE and for GlassFish, I can't quite remember."

So it might work on your platform, but don't expect the behaviour to be portable across servers or even different versions of the same application server.